# How to place center of layout on top-right corner of another layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have:

```
<RelativeLayout style="@style/w_w"
  android:gravity="top|center" 
  android:layout_marginBottom="10sp">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon" style="@style/w_w"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
    /> 
    <TextView android:text="F" android:id="@+id/temp" style="@style/w_w"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="top|center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`@style/w_w` - layout_height="wrap_content"=layout_width.

Now `<TextView />`'s right-top is in right-top corner of `<RelativeLayout />`, but I'd like to place `<TextView />`'s center in right-top corner of `<ImageViwq />`.

How should I construct my XML file?

Comment: can you please add some visual of how you actually want it. Description you gave is not that much clear.

Comment: @akkilis [look](http://vk.com/doc16200012_97027462?hash=49ee14265d14baae34)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this on your small view

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"
android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
```

Adjust the "-5dip"s if need be. This value should be roughly half the size of your small View.

Answer (score 0):

Use **android:layout_alignParent** & adjust **android:layout_margin** to get the view what ever you want...